# Too big of data in one line -- how to limit?

Tags: java, android, json, out-of-memory

Title is a bit ambiguous, but what I mean is:

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

      String line;
      JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

          ja = new JSONArray(line);
      }
      rd.close();
      return ja;

    }
```

If rd.readLine() returns a HUGE amount of data, how can I split it, or limit it? I'm getting an outofmemoryerror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options 
1) Store it as part of App by adding it to assests 
2) Redesign your data. Most of the times the data you are retrieving in this single call may not be useful at that perticular time. I would suggest split your data retrieval as needed basis. Because of Dalvik VM you don't have options to increase heap-size, so you have to think of these alternatives to come out of this OutofMemoryError.

Comment: these are good. my only question is: how would I go about splitting this data? How can I check how huge the data is before actually retrieving it?

Comment: Are you getting it from third party? Do you have any control over the datasource? For example, if you are listing states in country, if you have control over datasource, instead of getting all countries and corresponding states, change datasource service to take country as parameter and return only states in that country. If you don't have control over datasource, I think the approach you may have to do is, have a intermediatare hosted by you some where and get only data required from intermediatary (Let your intermediatary have that huge data).

Comment: well the problem is that the data that is required is too large. i am in control of the data source, but its about as elegant as i can make it. the only way i see of doing it, is splitting it based on how large it is, but i dont know how to check how large the data is before actually retrieving it and causing out of memory error

Comment: May I know the purpose you are using this data for? like populating some field or something? I will see if I can help anything there. I think you need to slice this issue from other side than worrying about checking how large the data is.

Comment: yeah, im using the data to populate a gridview in the android. basically im taking search results (large search results)

Comment: May be gridview with pagination (retrieve data on scroll, like how gmail app retrieves mails after 50 emails when you scroll up)? that way you can set limit on number of records getting displayed at a time and data will be less. I don't know it will make sense for your requirement but shedding some light.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense for sure. and thats exactly how i'd do it, but i still have to break the data up somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the Jackson JSON library for JSON parsing on Android. It's the fastest and will most likely have handling for large lines of JSON built into it's code.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing the java heap-size (-Xmx)? The default can be pretty small.

Comment: actually this can't work. it's the dalvikVM that's running out of heap memory since i'm programming for the android. do you know of better ways to read a large response from a website?